# Updated Exp:resso Store to 2.1 - Shipping methods field is empty

Tags: expresso-store

[image: Shopping Cart Checkout Page]

We recently updated from Exp:resso Store 1.6 to 2.1 and after the update our client's shipping information is blank.

I looked at the documentation and it appears as though everything should work as it stands.

Below is the shipping code used in the template:

```
<tr>
<td>Shipping</td>
<td colspan="2">
{field:shipping_method}
{if error:shipping_method}<p class="help-block">{error:shipping_method}</p>{/if}
</td>
<td style="text-align:right">{order_shipping}</td>
</tr>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add some screenshots of the shipping methods and rules you have set up?

Comment: https://www.beansmith.com/files/Screen_Shot_2013-12-08_at_10.08.06_PM.png

https://www.beansmith.com/files/Screen_Shot_2013-12-09_at_10.10.53_AM.png

Comment: Can you also provide a screenshot of the Countries / States tab? Have you allowed the user to enter any shipping details such as country/state/zip? Also it is a good idea to create a catchall rule that Any / Any that would be evaluated for any cart no matter what the location is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have only created shipping rules for Hong Kong and United States, the most likely explanation is that your current cart does not have a shipping country set. In Store 2, if there are no rules matching the current cart for a particular shipping method, that method no longer displays in the checkout (since it is effectively unavailable).

To fix this, you should set a default country for new carts. You can do this under Store > Settings > Countries / States. Make sure to empty your cart after changing this setting, as it only applies to new carts. You can verify this is correct by displaying the `{shipping_country}` variable in your template.

Answer (score 1):

After updating and getting some good feedback Exp:resso, we found that the update added a variable where the rule applied to carts from $0 - $0; thus it would never display.